# Submitted data not rendering without refresh - react

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting out with react and I have created a component to add data to my database, and the data saves, however the UI does not update without refreshing. What am I missing?

The first component I created is a search component that actually also does the main iteration and rendering of data, and this works great. However, the new data component is giving me hassles.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

============= Current main component ========

```
class Fruits extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      term: '',
      filtered: [],
      itemSelected: {},
      showItemSelected: false
    };
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/fruits/search?query=' + this.state.term)
    .then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((data) => {this.setState({ filtered: data }) });
  }

  handleSearch(e){
    this.setState({
      term: e.target.value
    }, () => {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/fruits/search?query=' + this.state.term)
    .then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((data) => {this.setState({ filtered: data }) });
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
    });
  }

  render(){
    let autoCompleteList = this.state.filtered.map((response, index) => {
      return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{response.name}</td>
        <td>{response.description}</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      )
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <AddFruit handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
        <input ref={ (input) => { this.searchBar = input } } value={ this.state.term } onChange={ this.handleSearch } className="form-control col-md-4" type='text' placeholder='Search...' />
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Fruit Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          { autoCompleteList }
          </tbody> 
        </table>
      </div>
  )
  }
}
```

================ New Data Component ========

```
class AddFruit extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initialState = { name: '', description: '' };
        this.state = this.initialState;
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        this.setState({
            [name] : value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/fruits', {
            method: 'POST',
            body:   JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.name,
                description: this.state.description
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        }).then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200) {
                    this.setState(this.initialState);
                }
        }); 
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control mb-2" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Name"/>
                    <input type="text" name="description" className="form-control mx-sm-3 mb-2" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Description"/>
                    <input className="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="submit"  value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: are you fetching the data again from server  after saving???

Comment: I am resetting the form after submit. Pardon my ignorance, but what would be the best way to re-fetch the data after submit?

Comment: Pass a function as prop from parent to child to fetch data and on sucess call it

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, I was abvle to follow from @tarzen chugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things that has to be improved:-

1) You are calling `<AddFruit handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>` but you are defining `handleSubmit` in `AddFruit` component itself instead of `Fruits` component. You could define handleSubmit inside Fruits component that will do the trick or if you want to define handleSubmit in AddFruit then go with next steps.

2) Once you add new Fruit, you should tell the parent component to fetch fruits again.

3) You should be calling fetch fruits in componentDidMount instead of constructor. Better create new function.

```
fetchFruits () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/fruits/search?query=' + this.state.term)
    .then((response) => {return response.json()})
    .then((data) => {this.setState({ filtered: data }) });
}

componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchFruits()
}

addFruitCallback() = () => {
    this.fetchFruits()
}

<AddFruit addFruitCallback={addFruitCallback} /> // pass callback when fruit is added.
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, and this got me sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The 'filtered' state is not updated after making POST call from the child.
In handleSubmit after POST call success , communicate it to parent and update the 'filtered' state by making one more API call.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sending the handleSubmit() function to th parent component Fruits so that it is passed as props to the child component addfruit and then called in the child component. you will pass it exactly as you did here `<AddFruit handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>` but the function

```
    handleSubmit(fruitObject) {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/fruits', {
            method: 'POST',
            body:   JSON.stringify(fruitObject),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        }).then((response) => {return response.json()})
          .then((fruit) => {this.setState({ filtered: [...this.state.filtered, fruit] })
           }); 
    }

 will be inside of  Fruit component.

So inside of your AddFruit Component You just need to call this function 
that was passed as props to it with the fruit you want to add.
Aso that is supposing that your API returns the Added fruit after adding it to the database.
```